# RegisterClientScriptBlock does not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

This is the scenario, I have button and when the user click it should check first the database then if it null the clientscript will appear and if the user click ok the session will be end but my code doesn't work. Anyone can help? Thank you!

```
protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (logout.checkLogoutGuest(""))
   {  
     ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "ScriptKey", "alert('There guest that didn't logged out.');window.location='Login.aspx'; ", true);

     int id = logout.selectLogin();
     logout.updateLogin(id, DateTime.Now.ToString());

     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();


   }
   else{


     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
     Session.Abandon();

     int id = logout.selectLogin();
     logout.updateLogin(id, DateTime.Now.ToString());

     Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", false);

    }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your redirecting page path and also browser console for any other errors.

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
    "ScriptKey", "alert('There guest that didn't logged out.');window.location = '/absolutepath'", true);
```

Comment: I check already check my redirecting page path and also the browser console but no found errors.